# Responsive sizing with SVG clipPath

Tags: css, svg, clip-path

I would like to mask an image for a design with a rounded hexagon. I think the ideal option would be the CSS clip-path property, but it doesn't seem to allow for rounded hexagons—unless there is a tool that allows you to upload shapes to it and it generates the polygon code. I've found [Clippy](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) and [CSS Plant's generator](http://www.cssplant.com/clip-path-generator), but neither allow you to upload or easily generate rounded shapes.

SVG `clipPath` is the other option. The main issue with this option is it isn't responsive. I'd like the SVG shape to be the max-width of it's container and fit the image within it, but it doesn't seem to do that—at least with the CSS I have now. This is what I've been working with: https://codepen.io/apautler/pen/eMBEoO. I looked into `objectBoundingBox`, but I can't seem to get that to work either.

Any help that can point me in the right direction of how to get a rounded hexagon that is responsive would be very helpful.

Comment: can use svg compulsory otherwise can done using css also to become this shape

Comment: Try generate using this http://csshexagon.com/

Comment: @sharvan, I found that generator, but that creates a hexagon via pseudo elements, not the CSS clip-path polygon option. Not sure what you mean by svg compulsory though.

Comment: I was able to find this tool: http://betravis.github.io/shape-tools/path-to-polygon/ that converts SVG shapes into polygons. I seems to work pretty well to do what I want, so I uploaded a hexagon with tons of points around the rounded corners, so it appears smooth. It works, but if anyone else has other ideas, I'm still open to them.